# Webgl strange float math

Tags: floating-point, webgl, precision

One gets strange results when modifying values of float variables inside a conditional statement when a uniform or texture coordinates are used in the condition. This happens inside a fragment shader on numerous mobile devices like iPhone 4S, iPhone 5, iPhone 5S, iPhone 6 (Safari, Chrome and Firefox), Samsung J3 (Android browser, Chrome) and quite possibly others.
It seems the value can be compared to another float, but when is divided one gets zero if the divisor is more than half bigger than the value.
Here is a simple test case. All values of R, G and B colors are expected to be the same 128 and the output should be thus grey, however on these mobile devices one gets R equal to zero and so the output is of sea color.
The jsfiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/d4waymcL/)

The html is:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Hello</title>
</head>
<body>
    <script src="js/shadertest.js"></script>
</body>
```

The js code is:

```
    function test(){
    var create3DContext = function(canvas, opt_attribs) {
      var names = ["webgl", "experimental-webgl", "webkit-3d", "moz-webgl"];
      var context = null;
      for (var ii = 0; ii < names.length; ++ii) {
        try {
          context = canvas.getContext(names[ii], opt_attribs);
        } catch(e) {}
        if (context) {
          break;
        }
      }
      return context;
    }

    var compileShader = function(type, source) {
        var shader = gl.createShader(type);
        gl.shaderSource(shader, source);
        gl.compileShader(shader);

        if( !gl.getShaderParameter(shader, gl.COMPILE_STATUS) ) {
            throw new Error(gl.getShaderInfoLog(shader));
        }

        return shader;
    };

    var canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
    canvas.width = 1;
    canvas.height = 1;
    canvas.style.width = '100%';
    canvas.style.height = '100%';
    document.body.appendChild(canvas);

    var gl = create3DContext(canvas, {});

    // init buffers
    var buffer = gl.createBuffer();
    gl.bindBuffer(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, buffer);
    gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, new Float32Array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1]), gl.STATIC_DRAW);

    // The main IDWT Shader
    var webglProgram = gl.createProgram();
    gl.attachShader(webglProgram, compileShader(gl.VERTEX_SHADER, SHADER_VERTEX_IDENTITY));
    gl.attachShader(webglProgram, compileShader(gl.FRAGMENT_SHADER, SHADER_FRAGMENT));

    gl.linkProgram(webglProgram);



    if( !gl.getProgramParameter(webglProgram, gl.LINK_STATUS) ) {
        throw new Error(gl.getProgramInfoLog(webglProgram));
    }

    gl.useProgram(webglProgram);


    var vertexAttr = gl.getAttribLocation(webglProgram, 'vertex');
    gl.enableVertexAttribArray(vertexAttr);
    gl.vertexAttribPointer(vertexAttr, 2, gl.FLOAT, false, 0, 0);

    gl.uniform1i(gl.getUniformLocation(webglProgram, 'vertical'), 0);

    gl.viewport(0, 0, 1, 1);

    gl.drawArrays(gl.TRIANGLE_STRIP, 0, 4);

    var pixels = new Uint8Array(4);
    var imgData = gl.readPixels(0,0,1,1,gl.RGBA,gl.UNSIGNED_BYTE, pixels);
    console.log('R = '+pixels[0]);
    console.log('G = '+pixels[1]);
    console.log('B = '+pixels[2]);
    console.log('A = '+pixels[3]);
}
var SHADER_FRAGMENT = [

        'precision mediump float;',

        'uniform int vertical;',

        'void main() {',
            'float valueLow  = 60.0;',
            'float valueHigh = 60.0;',
            'if ( vertical == 1)',
            '{',
                'valueLow = 60.0;',
            '}',
            'gl_FragColor.rgba = vec4((valueLow+10000.0)/20000.0, (valueHigh+10000.0)/20000.0, (60.0+10000.0)/20000.0, 1.0);',
        '}'
    ].join('\n'),
SHADER_VERTEX_IDENTITY = [
    'attribute vec2 vertex;',
    'varying vec2 texCoord;',

    'void main() {',
        'texCoord = vertex;',
        'gl_Position = vec4((vertex * 2.0 - 1.0) * vec2(1, -1), 0.0, 1.0);',
    '}'
].join('\n');
test();
```

**EDIT**
I found one workaround which is to move the math with the variable in question inside the same conditional statement like in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zfas53c8/), but I hope there is a more elegant way.

Comment: " It seems the value can be compared to another float, but when is divided one gets zero if the divisor is more than half bigger than the value." - sounds suspiciously like integer division!

Comment: @MitchWheat, yes, something like it or maybe there was a precision change, but why is that and how to remedy it ?, casting it to float like float(valueLow) does not change the result

Comment: G and B are statically resolved at compile time with full 32 bit precision. R is resolved at runtime with the low prescision of mobile devices.

Comment: @pleup, so what would be the recommended remedy for this ?

Comment: Avoid having float values exceeding precision range of your hardware. Your example make useless math, what is your real case?

Comment: @pleup, my real math is quite complex. So on these mobiles at runtime there is only low precision math available and that should be the answer ?

Comment: @pleup, also please see the jsfiddle in the EDIT, it does work though it seems to me that it is does it at runtime like in the first example, why then ?

Comment: In your edit, all components can be infered at compile time. Also, Gl_FragColor is undefined if condition is false, which will lead to weird result on ios.

Comment: Most modern phones support highp. use `precision highp float` or mark specific variables as highp. You can use `#if GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH` if you want to support older phones. Also while we're at it `moz-webgl` and `webkit-3d` never existed in shipping webgl. Also [multiline template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) exist everywhere except IE and no one running IE still is likely to be on a machine that can run WebGL

Comment: @pleup, certainly cannot agree on this one, the original example and the edit both have condition that is determined by a uniform. A better test is this one [link](https://jsfiddle.net/x3z9br4c/) and [link](https://jsfiddle.net/cuh6y9p3/) - the only difference is the position of the color flag, yet the first one fails and the second one works on mobiles

Comment: https://gist.github.com/plepers/a4b8ab2f4a7f411057d0d2aa6455c358

Comment: @pleup, thanks for this and what about the original example, can the optimizer not do it in the same way ?

Comment: @gman, thanks, so how would you one put it, the precision drops one step at runtime ? If you specify precision mediump float you get low precision at runtime and if you specify precision highp float you get medium at runtime, or how does this work ?

Comment: If you do change the value of 'valueLow' in the if block, the division need to be made at runtime. The optimizer probably don't check that the value in the if block is the same that the initial value. Maybe some more advanced optimizer could do it... I've update the gist and add an example that should work.

Comment: @pleup, Ok, great, so in my test examples it was a case of optimizer issue, but different devices have different ranges for the same precision and so one has to account for this(like using getShaderPrecisionFormat). If you could post it as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know how to work around low percision issues except to change your math not to run into the but you can conditionally ask for high percision

```
#if GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
  precision highp float;
#else
  precision mediump float;
#else
```

Most modern phones support highp at the expense of speed but some older ones like an iPhone3GS don't.

You can also set the precision of specific variables

```
#if GL_FRAGMENT_PRECISION_HIGH
  highp vec3 someVar;
#else
  mediump vec3 someVar;
#else
```

On desktop you just always get highp regardless of what you ask for which is fine as far as the spec in concerned.